# What is causing the index of a string in Uint8Array to be offset?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, file, wav

I'm trying to analyse wave files using the File API.

I need to find the index of a string inside the header of a file, in order to grab the subsequent data.

I have tried converting the string and matching the raw bytes in a `for` loop, but that proved to be a big performance killer when analysing 10k+ files.

I'm now trying to find it using `TextDecoder()` and `indexOf`.

```
// buffer is a (part of) a wave file as ArrayBuffer 
const array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
const string = new TextDecoder().decode(array);
const index = string.indexOf('fmt');
```

This will give me an index. However, when perform a little check up and confirm I have the right chunk ...

```
const check = array.slice(index, index + 4);
```

I get varying results for the chunk identifier (the string, in this case, 'FMT'). For example:

```
console.log(check);
// [102, 109, 116, 32]
```

or:

```
console.log(check);
// [0, 102, 109, 116]
```

The index I'm getting will sometimes be offset by -2, -1 or 0. It's a little unreliable.

I guess my question is: **What is causing this weird offset?**

Please don't refer me to third party libraries to analyse .wav files, I'd love to get this working / understand why it will never work.

Comment: So, from **the same input**, you are getting different logs?

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript uses Unicode, and that `TextDecoder()` as you're using it will interpret the bytes as UTF-8. Some Unicode code points consume more than one byte (up to 3 in UTF-8).

Comment: @briosheje I am expecting the same result because I am inputting the same string. That string will give me different indexes depending on the file analysed, but when using that index on the original buffer to slice it, I get different outputs

Comment: @Pointy That is probably the issue, is there a solution to compensate for this?

Comment: Well you can iterate through the string (which will be UTF-16, not UTF-8, because JavaScript strings are always UTF-16) and look for "big" characters, but that puts you more-or-less right back where you started.